# Infinite subset contains finite subset of any size

Tags: set-theory

Is it true in ZF that given any infinite set $X$ and any natural number $n$, there is a subset of $X$ with cardinality $n$ (i.e. equinumerous with $n$)?

Here, $X$ is defined to be an infinite set if $X$ is not equinumerous to any natural number $n$.

This may turn out to be quite trivial, but I can't think of an argument to show this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slight variant on the answer by Alex. It assumes that you already proved some basic things about finite sets and their cardinality.

Given an infinite set $S$, we prove by induction that for every $n$, there exists $S_n\subseteq S$ of size $n$.

For $n=0$, the only set of size $0$ is $\varnothing$, and since $\varnothing$ is a subset of any other set, in particular it is a subset of $S$.

Suppose that there is a subset $S_n\subseteq S$ of size $n$, since $S$ is not finite it cannot be that $S_n=S$; therefore there exists $s\in S\setminus S_n$, and now $S_n\cup\{s\}$ is a set of size $n+1$ as wanted.

---

Now let me leave you with something to contemplate on: The above proof is not enough to conclude that $S$ has a countably infinite subset. Why?

Comment: Is this because mathematical induction doesn't extend to the infinite, and to extend it to the infinite, we need some form of the axiom of choice, say the axiom of countable choice?

Comment: Yes, that is why. Although you need slightly more than countable choice.

Comment: Don't you need Choice already to pick a new element from the original set?  That's an example of something I've wondered about: if it works no matter which element you pick, is it still Choice, and would the proof still work if you could not order the particular elements?

Comment: @JDługosz: No. Choosing one element is guaranteed to us by the rules of logic; choosing finitely many is guaranteed to us by induction. Here at each step we only chose two things: the set of size $n$ and an element not in that set. The proof didn't argue that you can create a sequence of all these $S_n$'s. Just that you can find such $S_n$ for every $n$, separately.

Answer (score 3):

We proceed by induction:

Let $S$ be an infinite set. Let $a\in S$. By the axiom of subsets, there exists a subset $A\subset S$ such that $x\in A\Rightarrow x=a$. By the axiom of extensionality, $A=\{a\}$. Thus, we can get a subset of size $1$.

Now suppose that we can get a subset $K$ of size $n$, meaning we have a bijection from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $K$. By the axiom of subsets, there is a subset $K^C$ of $S$ satisfying $x\in K^C\Leftrightarrow x\not\in K$. If $K^C$ is empty, then $K$ and $S$ have the same elements. By the axiom of extensionality, $K=S$, so there is a bijection from $\{1,...,n\}$ to $S$, a contradiction. Therefore there exists $b\in K^C$. By the argument above, there exists a set $B=\{b\}$. By the axiom of unordered pairs, there exists a set $\{K,B\}$. By the axiom of the sum set, there exists a set $K'$ containing all the elements of $K$ and $B$. Let $g:\{1,...,n+1\}to K'$ be defined by $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in K$ and $g(x)=b$ is $x\in B$. This is clearly a bijection, so $K'$ has size $n+1$.

Comment: What about the empty set? Isn't it finite? :-(

Comment: The OP says that $n\in\mathbb N$, which I consider to be $\{1,2,3,...\}$. But if you insist, the axiom of subsets says that there exists a subset $E$ such that $x\in E\Leftrightarrow x\not\in S$. Then $E$ is empty.

Comment: But $0$ is a natural number. Otherwise you can't say that the natural numbers corresponds exactly to the finite cardinals. Because I'll be darned if $|\varnothing|$ is not a finite cardinal.